# rails: display unique records in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a product display page which is displaying all products on website. Here I want to filter products as per their Owner. As a start, i am displaying owner names on page using each loop:

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
   <%= link_to p.user.profile.first_name, store_index_path %>
<% end %>
```

But as owner has multiple products, his name gets displayed multiple times. How to show the name only once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simple way you can do like this:

```
<% @products.map(&:user).uniq.each do |u| %>
  <%= link_to u.profile.first_name, store_index_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `.()` is an alias for `proc#call`; I don't think that will work.

Comment: @checkit hey can you help me in next step? As we have all owners list now, i want to display products of owner when user click on his name. How to do this?

Comment: You have to create an action in controller. Then use `<%= link_to 'User name', :action => 'user_products', :params => {:user => user %>` . Here `user_products` is an controller action. There you get user in params as `params[:user]`. `@user_products = Product.where(:user => params[:user])`

Comment: To get all products of user: `@user_products = Product.where(:user_id => params[:user])`

Comment: @checkit hey didnt get this line: <%= link_to 'User name', :action => 'user_products', :params => {:user => user %> Can you correct it?

Comment: `<%= link_to u.profile.first_name, store_index_path(:search=>params[:search], :user=>user) %>`. Then in controller `@products = User.find(params[:user]).products.all`

Comment: I think `params[:user]` is `nil`. Can you check why its `nil`?? .. `<%= link_to u.profile.first_name, store_index_path(:search=>params[:search], :user=>u) %>` it should be `u` not `user`

Comment: it is showing error on my store controller: here: @products = Product.search(params)

Comment: `@products = Product.search(params)` will work when you have `params[:user_id]` not `params[:user]`. So in `link_to` change `:user` to `:user_id`

Comment: <%= link_to u.profile.first_name, store_index_path(:search=>params[:search], :user_id=>u) %> it is like this now. But still same error. @checkit

Answer (score 1):

You can use group_by to create a hash of User => [Products].  Then, you iterate through the unique set of Users, display the information about that owner, and then display each product for that User.

```
<% products_by_owner = @product.group_by(&:user) %>
<% products_by_owner.keys.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to p.user.profile.first_name, store_index_path %>
  <% products_by_owner[user].each do |product| %>
    <%= link_to product.name, store_index_path %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by` to create a hash with the users as keys and arrays of products as values:

```
# Eager loading of users will prevent multiple database hits.
# Using find:
@products = Product.find(:all, :include => :user).group_by(&:user)

# using relations:
@products = Product.where(:some_condition => 'etc').includes(:user).group_by(&:user)
```

In the view:

```
<% @products.each do |user, user_products| %>
  <%= link_to p.user.profile.first_name, store_index_path %>
  <% user_products.each do |product| %>
     ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```